# How do I relatively stretch two series with a different number of indexes in the same graph using chartist js?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chartist.js

#### Prelude

Using Chartist I know that there is an option to "fill holes" in two different data sets that don't have an equivalent amount of items like the following example:

```js
var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  series: [
    [5, 5, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4],
    [10, 15, null, 12, null, null, null]
  ]
}, {
  lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.cardinal({
    fillHoles: true,
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
```

Notice in the example the second series will only show a line up to the last value that is not `null` (at index 4).

#### Question

Is there a way to get chartist to make the second series relative to the first, spreading the second series line to match the first one up until the last value of the longest series?

Comment: So you want to have the `12` (last non-null value in series 2) be at X = 7, matching the `4` (last non-null) value of series 1, and spread the remaining values in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some helpers that modify your data arrays:

- `trimNulls` removes any `null` values from the start and end of an array:

  ```
  [10, 15, null, 12, null, null, null] -> [10, 15, null, 12]
  ```
- `stretch` takes an array and a required length and distributes the original values to new indexes:

  ```
  [10, 15, null, 12] -> 7 -> [10, null, 15, null, null, null, 12]
  ```
- `alignSeries` takes a list of data series and aligns each of them to the widest one.

  ```
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4], [null, 1, 4] ] -> 
    [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, null, null, 4], [1, null, null, 4] ]
  ```

In a running example, with the old line included for reference:

```js
const trimNulls = (data) => {
  // Find the first non-null value
  const start = data.findIndex(y => y !== null);
  // Find the last non-null value
  const end = data.length - Array.from(data).reverse()
                                 .findIndex(y => y !== null);
  // Return the elements between those boundaries                               
  return data.slice(start, end);
}

const stretch = (data, newLength) => {
  // Create array of required number of nulls
  const stretched = Array(newLength).fill(null);
  // Determine the stretch factor
  const s = newLength / data.length;
  // For every value we want to keep, place it
  // at its new, stretched index
  data.forEach((y, x) => {
    stretched[Math.ceil(x * s)] = y;
  });
  // Return the newly created array
  return stretched;
}

// Takes a list of series and aligns their starts and ends, stretching 
// in between
const alignSeries = series => {
  // Trim each series
  const trimmed = series.map(trimNulls);
  // Find the longest one
  const maxLength = Math.max(...trimmed.map(t => t.length));
  // Stretch all series to the longest length and return
  return trimmed.map(t => stretch(t, maxLength));
};

var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  series: [
    ...alignSeries([
      [5, 5, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4],
      [10, 15, null, 12, null, null, null]
    ]),
    // For reference
    [10, 15, null, 12, null, null, null]
  ]
}, {
  lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.cardinal({
    fillHoles: true,
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think this hits the nail on the head! I didn't think of the solution coming from manipulating the array! I thought chartist might have this built in and I couldn't find it